# How to append text from one txt file to multiple txt files in batch?

Tags: windows, batch

I have one `.txt` file with some text that I want to append to all `.txt` files in a folder.

Can anyone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to replace the existing content of the other files, or do you want to append the text to the existing file contents? (Or anything else?)

Comment: I want to append the text to the existing file contents...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to rename the file which should be appended to `append_me` (or anything without `.txt` extension), then you can use a FOR loop over `*.txt` files in a batch file `append.bat`:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do type append_me >> %%a
```

- `@` suppresses the printing of the follwing command line prior to execution
- `echo off` does the same for all following commands
- `%%a` defines a variable, which takes (one after another) the `*.txt` file names (*)
- `type` displays the file content (Linux analogon is `cat`)
- `>>` appends that content to the current file (`%%a`)

---

(*) If you use that command directly on the command line, use only `%a`; see `for /?` for the complete syntax of `for` loops.